# What is the difference between "obdurate" and "obstinate"?

Tags: differences, synonyms

I saw the former for the first time today, but I noticed its definition seems exactly like the latter. Is there something I'm missing or are the two just pure synonyms?

Comment: You could try a few more dictionaries, until you perceive a difference. *Obdurate* carries a sense of hardened; thus an older person may be hardened, or obdurate, but a child can be obstinate without being obdurate.

Comment: Maybe obstinate has more negative connotations? Is obdurate more likely to be used of someone standing fast for good reason, and obstinate someone standing fast just to be awkward? Although that could just be because obstinate is more commonly used of a child. And this is connected to Xanne's answer: obstinate is being obstructive for no reason, obdurate has a reason (character, a hard skin, toughness, standing fast for what you believe).

Comment: The roots actually give a good account. _Dur-_ has to do with perseverance over time: _endure, duration, durable, during_, hence toughness. _Sta-_, on the other hand, has to do with standing rigid: _stand, stable, staff, stamen_, more a matter of internal rigidity than external toughness. The _ob-_ is the same in each case, 'against'.

Comment: I found the explanation [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/logophilia/comments/2qp4bj/obdurate_obstinate/) pretty enlightening, based on the latin roots of the two words.

Answer (score 3):

**Stubborn** - A tendency *of disposition* to persist in an opinion, belief, decision, or course of action, generally with more force than reason.

**Obstinate** - A particular instance of stubborn behavior.

*Dick had always been a **stubborn** boy, but he was particularly **obstinate** in his dislike of homework.*

**Obdurate** - A hard and unyielding attitude of a harsh and unfeeling character.

*The foreman was **obdurate** in holding to rigid production schedules.*

**Source**: *Choose the Right Word*, by S.I. Hayakawa

**Note**: I had looked up this same cluster of synonyms in the past with Webster's dictionary of synonyms and found the same explanatory distinctions.